# Travel ban order: why those countries?

Tags: united-states, executive, executive-order

[The Executive Order "Protecting the Nation from Foreign Terrorist Entry into the United States"](https://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2017/01/27/executive-order-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states) has been criticized by opponents for the selection of countries on the list.

What is the basis for the specific list of countries included in the travel ban?

For example, why, say, Iraq and not Saudi Arabia?

Comment: @user4012: Which one?

Comment: +1 I am also curious about the origin of the list. I have heard the list of countries excludes Trump's business interests (with the implication that that was on purpose), but I have also heard that it was drawn up during the Obama administration.

Answer (score 0):

- The original list was produced in 2015 under something called the [Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq).
- That list was [amended in Feb 2016 to add 3 more countries to include all the countries now on the list](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/02/18/dhs-announces-further-travel-restrictions-visa-waiver-program).

Comment: Also worth noting that in his order Trump directs administration to review all nations and suggest any that may need to be added within 90 days. In other words Saudi Arabia may get on the list